# How far back in time does Here Isoline Departure field go?

Tags: gis, here-api

When calling the Isoline API, how far back in history can we enter for the Departure field?

And is the data static after that date has passed?

Answer (score 0):

Departure field works only if set to now or any future time. You cannot query the API for any past time or history.

Comment: If I set for a future time, how does the system estimate the travel time?

Comment: For a future time, the travel time is estimated based on the historic traffic data and current road conditions available with Here.

Comment: So is there any way to get a static Isoline based on a specific day/time each time we call the API?